# Should water be dripping like this after installing drip edge flashings?

Tags: water, roof

We saw water dripping like this in the morning from the morning dew. We recently had a contractor replace our roof on the house and the contractor said this was due to installing new drip edge flashings. I was just wondering if this was normal as the contractor mentioned.

[image: Photo of water drip]

Comment: What's the big white thing on the roof near the corner.  It looks like the dew is dripping from that.

Comment: Looks to me if there's dew dripping it's from the corner of the gutter.  The center of the dampness is offset too far from the wall to be the white thing on the roof.  Also looks to be a similar spot at the other end of the gutter?